# Update /etc/crontab to quit a process as root every other minute during working hours

Tags: 16.04, cron, time, etc

How can i update /etc/crontab to quit a process as root every other minute during working hours, as in this case is 0800-1600, monday-saturday. How can I also allow the same process to be active between 12.00-12.30 and between 16:00-07:59?

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

Comment: Don't you know the command to run or how to setup the timetable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set this up in just *one* crontab line (at least I don't know a way right now) so you have to setup *two* jobs:

- one for the hours 8-11 and 13-15 that runs every minute (i.e. 08:00-11:59 and 13:00-15:59)
- and one for the minutes 31-59 in hour 12 (i.e. 12:31-12:59)

```
*     8-11,13-15 * * 1-6 /usr/bin/killall firefox
31-59    12      * * 1-6 /usr/bin/killall firefox
```

The `1-6` means monday to saturday

Add these to lines not to `/etc/crontab` but to `root`'s crontab instead by issuing

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Change the command (`killall …`) to your needs.